# What's the difference of the fonts starting with @ symbol?

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

I'm  using PowerBuilder 12.5 since it is released. Today I realized that there are font names (in the dropdown list which appears when Datawindow Painter is opened) starting with an `@` symbol. There is about thirty of them and the same font names without `@` already exist in the same list.
(i.e. `@Arial Unicode MS` and `Arial Unicode MS`).

The question is what is the difference between those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've also asked this question on `forum.sybase.com` newsgroups under `sybase.public.powerbuilder.general` and seems like the best answer is that [@ fonts are for 90° rotated vertical text](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/07/19/10331400.aspx).

Thanks to `Roland Smith [TeamSybase]` and `Reed Shilts [Sybase]`.